# Add a workflow option missing

Tags: workflow-settings

I have a web application with multiple site collection. The issue I am facing is one of this site collection do not showing add a workflow option in all list / libraries. Please see below screenshot for same:

[image]

I have checked the site collection features & site features. The working site collection and this one has same features activated.  I have no idea where to look now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To have workflows available in the site collection, we need to enable some features realated to workflows as per the requirement.

To have `out-of-the-box` workflows on the site collection, please check if site collection features : `Workflows` & `Disposition Approval Workflow` is enabled or not.

Comment: Both of this features are activate. I have tried deactivating / activating them, but still same issue.

Comment: For me it worked for `Disposition Approval Workflow` feature. Any way I will get back to you if I find something else.